# try to print some table is sqlite3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

hi I am a new in python i tried to create a new class that handle with sqlite3 in my read method i try to print some var but is does not print anything can you help me?
here is the code can you fix it and tell me what the problem is

```
class  SQLite_class() :
    file_name=''
    table_sql_name =''
   # con = sqlite3.connect(self.c)
    def creat_file_name(self):
        self.file_name = input("enter the SQL fille name !")
        self.file_name = self.file_name+'.sqlite'
        return self.file_name
    def conncection(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.file_name)
        return conn
    def creat_cursor(self):
        conn = self.conncection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        return cur
    def del_table(self):
        cur = self.creat_cursor()
        cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+self.table_sql)
    def creat_table(self):
        cur = self.creat_cursor()
        #adding a new option (name of table of more we need to add some {} and use the format function)
        cur.execute( '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (data TEXT, number INTEGER)'''.format(self.table_sql_name))
        self.commiting()
    def insrt(self):
        cur = self.creat_cursor()
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO {} (data, number) VALUES (?, ?)'''.format(self.table_sql_name) ,('Thunderstruck', 20))
    def close(self):
      conn = self.conncection()
      conn.close()
    def commiting(self):
        conn = self.conncection()
        conn.commit()
    def read(self):
        cur = self.creat_cursor()
        cur.execute('''SELECT data, number FROM {}'''.format(self.table_sql_name))
        for row in cur: print(row)
test = SQLite_class()

test.creat_file_name()
test.table_sql_name = 'Track'
test.creat_table()
test.insrt()
test.commiting()
test.read()
test.commiting()
test.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment `# con = sqlite3.connect(self.c)` indicates you know what has to be done. I suspect when that didn't work, you went down the rabbit hole of creating connections everywhere.  Program should make one db connection. Every time it makes a connection, it loses what came before.

It could declare `conn = ''`, then call `conncection()` once (and remove it from the other methods; they'll probably need to take `conn` as an argument). It'll take some try, try again, but it will get you to a better place.

And don't forget to `fetch` the rows once the SELECT is executed.